# How to download files as soon as user's mobile is connected to internet?

Tags: android, parse-platform, android-service

I'm working on a project which requires data to be downloaded to user's phone(Android) as and when he is connected to the internet. This should be ***irrespective*** of whether the application is in foreground or not.

PS:

- I know how to download files from server and store it in user's phone, what I don't know is how to automate this process when connected to the internet.
- I'm using Parse.com if that helps in any way.

Thanks.

**Edit:** I want a solution, similar to how play store auto-updates app without user's themselves opening play store.

Comment: check the user internet connection in a method like `onCreate` if it was available start the download process

Comment: But wouldn't that require the app to be opened first? I want the download to begin even when user has no interaction with the app, similar to play store which auto-updates app without user opening play store itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do it. I am writing steps here.

1. Implement internet connection broadcast receiver.
2. Create a Service by extending an IntentService and put your code in
   service for download data from server.
3. You will got the call back in internet connection broadcast receiver
   when internet connection changes.Start your service if connection is
   alive.

[Example1](https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html)
[Example2](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2011/10/android-intentservice-example-using.html)

Comment: I'm relatively new to services. Could you pease provide some links or code on how to implement the above steps?

Answer (score 0):

You can not update (or install) an app without user-interaction, unless

1. You're a system app (custom ROM)
2. Your device is rooted and your updater has root privileges.

Further, there is no official API available to check the version of an app available in the Google Play store.

You can achieve some of what you are trying to do by keeping track of the current version outside of Google Play and then prompting to update the user by launching the market link. If you do that from a secondary app, you can even wait for the update to be complete and then re-launch the app.

In practice, you can't do silent installs/updates without user-interaction, and that's a Good Thing (tm), for the reasons that the first couple of commenters have stated.

**BUT** maybe this link could help you :
https://push-link.com/

Answer (score 0):

You should do this in AsyncTask's "do in background" ...if app needs this files in starting then do AsyncTask on SplashScreen ... make the AsyncTask executable in "if" condition ... this "if" statement will check presence on internet